# Email Already Taken, When update Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-formrequest

Heloo friend im dwi prihtapambudi, i using form request on laravel 8 to create validation, in the validation i have validation unique type on email, i try update data but i have error "email already taken" can sombody help me please

this is my model

```
 protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];
```

this is my controller

```
   public function store(UserRequest $request)
    {
        $data=$request->All();
        $data['password'] = Hash::make($request->password);
        User::updateOrCreate(['id'=>$request->id],$data);
        return response()->json($data);
    }
```

and this is my validation

```
  public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name'=>'required|string|min:1|max:60',
            'email'=>'required|string|email|unique:users|max:255',
            'password'=>'required|string|min:6',
            'password_confirm' => 'required|same:password',
        ];
    }
```

thanks for your atenttion guyss

Answer (score 4, accepted):

while updating ignore editing user record row from  unique validation

```
  'email'=>'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users,email,'.$this->id,
```

**Updated**:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class UserRequest  extends FormRequest
{

   private $defaultValidation=[];
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }


    public function rules()
    {
        $this->defaultValidation=[
            'name'=>'required|string|min:1|max:60',
            'email'=>'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users,email,'.$this->id,
        ];
        
        if(empty($this->id)){
            $this->defaultValidation['password']='required|string|min:6';
            $this->defaultValidation['password_confirm']='required|same:password';
        }


        switch ($this->method()) {

            case 'POST':
                return   $this->defaultValidation;;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return [];
    }


}
```

Comment: i have error like this SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'db_notaris_nanik.users6' doesn't exist (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `users6` where `email` = ewr5345@gmail.com)

Comment: sorry my mistake .updated.forgot  to add column name

Comment: i still have error, "The given data was invalid"

Comment: while editing you have pass id in request.it might be hidden field

Comment: can you dd( $this->all()) before return validation inside validation() method

Comment: like this array:7 [▼
  "_token" => "4L4fhooI2FXYGMfK05lFivIZ0bMQqbk7RROoqOtN"
  "id" => "6"
  "name" => "sdfsdfsdf"
  "email" => "ewr5345@gmail.com"
  "password" => null
  "password_confirm" => null
  "send" => "Kirimkan Data"
]

Comment: looks good.id exist.but still you get error ,check which validation rule fails.for checking purpose keep only email validation and other comment it .

Comment: ohh tanks jhon, it turns out that I have an error in my validation password, its word

Comment: i guess you have valdiation for password required but it in request it null so it throwing error i guess

Comment: have you any idea for my error validation password error ? i used same:password to match the password, but when i update the data i hide the password form with jquery

Comment: $additionalValidation=[];
 $defaultValidation=[
   'name'=>'required|string|min:1|max:60',
            'email'=>'required|string|email|unique:users|max:255',
  ];
  
  if(empty($this->id)){
   
   $additionalValidation=[
   'password'=>'required|string|min:6',
            'password_confirm' => 'required|same:password',
   ];
  
  }
  
 $validationRules=array_merge($defaultValidation, $additionalValidation); 
 
 return $validationRules;

Comment: beautifull, its work, thanks you so much my friend